# Google fruit object lifetime

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, google-fruit

What is the lifetime of objects created using google fruit?
We have a system that uses only one large component with a few dozen bindings. As far as I could tell, some bindings produce several instances when requested, while others are "singletons" (i.e. only one instance is created and passed to several requesting objects).
Most bindings are simple, i.e.:

```
.bind<Interface1, Impl1>
```

Though we also have a few factories:

```
 .registerFactory<unique_ptr<Interface2>(fruit::Assisted<const string&>)>(
    [](const string& arg) { return Impl2::Create(arg); })
```

In what situations will fruit create a new instance, and in what situations will it reuse existing instances?

This knowledge is important in deciding how to bind some services, since we want to make sure some of the bindings are "singular"/"singleton" in the application, and some are created each time they are requested.

Bonus question: If we extract some of the bindings to sub-components, how will that affect the lifetime of objects assuming we .install() all the sub-components into the main one?

**UPDATE:**
So we now know scope is supposed to be maintained by injectors. I ended up using a different solution, as follows:
I split our large component into a handful of smaller components, each created in a separate method. This made the component-building code look more like the examples in Fruit's site.
Then, for the components that need singleton values, I put a static member inside the method and used bindInstance, for example:

```
fruit::Component<SingletonInterface> CreateSingletonComponent()
{
    static MySingleton instance;
    return fruit::createComponent().bindInstance((SingletonInterface&)instance);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Google Fruit don't implement object scope/lifetime like Singleton, RequestScoped, SessionScoped, ThreadScoped.

From Google Fruit wiki (https://github.com/google/fruit/wiki):

> Injection scopes, e.g. binding a type/value only for the duration of a request. This feature was implemented and then removed, replaced by the use of NormalizedComponent. If you need to create many injectors that have most of the bindings in common, NormalizedComponent allows to save most of work involved in the injector creation (but there will still be separate injectors). See the server page in the tutorial for an example use of NormalizedComponent with per-request injectors.

Comment: It seems you're correct; scopes are meant to be implemented via Injector scopes:
"Normalized components are best suited if the vast majority of the bindings are common. A typical use case is in a server, where a separate injector is created for every request..."